# smbd/negprot.c:674(reply_negprot) No protocol supported?

Tags: samba

if anyone can help me it would be huge favor, so the thing is we have an old samba server 3.4 with Ubuntu for sharing files, so its working fine with all the others systems, except we have a system windows server 2008 which is not able to access the server every time I try accessing my files from windows server 2008 I get this message in samba logs

```
[2017/06/25 14:26:18, 0] smbd/negprot.c:674(reply_negprot)
No protocol supported !


smbd --version
Version 3.4.7
```

I have tried min and max protocols from

```
min protocol =
CORE
NT1
SMB1
SMB2
SMB3
```

still don't know what the error can be...
here is my configuration for smb

[Smb.conf configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6oyj.jpg)

[windows server error why i try accessing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQO3e.jpg)